# implementing UITextField with autocomplete on a backend

Tags: ios, swift

What would be the easiest way to implement a search text box with autocomplete that is connected to the backend call in IOS8 in swift?
I was thinking about UIAlertController but conceptually it seems to be only opening up as modal, blocking the text box input until it's dismissed.
I'm fairly new to IOS development, perhaps there is a different better way?

Comment: A quick google search returned me plenty of useful results

Comment: Maybe have a look at UISearchBar and UISearchController